# Infinite recursion for parsing arithmetic expressions using a recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent, infinite-recursion

I am trying to create my own recursive descent parser in python, but when my parser runs into a rule concerning arithmetic expressions, it surpasses the python recursion limit. Here is the grammar:

```
Term --> Factor {( "+" | "-" ) Factor}
Factor --> Grouping {( "*" | "/" | "%" ) Grouping}
Grouping --> Expression | "(" Expression ")" | "-" Factor


Expression --> Integer | Float | Tuple | ID | Term
```

The curly braces in the grammar denote that they can repeat (but also is optional), and are implemented using a while loop in my parser. I feel that what is causing this is the fact that a `Grouping` rule can be and `Expression` (whcih can recur over and over because the right side of the `Factor` and `Term` rule are optional).

What I am asking is: Is there a way to implement the left recusion with a recursive descent parser or eliminate it in my grammar somehow?

EDIT: I was browsing around and iit seem this type of recursion is called [indirect left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Indirect_left_recursion), perhaps this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, the infinite recursion is the result of the infinite loop

```
Expression ⇒ Term ⇒ Factor ⇒ Grouping ⇒ Expression
```

which must be broken. But it's a simple transcription error; `Expression` needs to start from the top, in a hierarchy of syntactic precedence:

```
Expression ⇒ Term {( "+" | "-" ) Term}
Term ⇒ Factor {( "*" | "/" | "%" ) Factor}
Factor ⇒ Item | "-" Factor
Item ⇒ Integer | Float | Tuple | ID | "(" Expression ")"
```